# Get absolute path from a Connected device. C#

Tags: c#, directory

When we connect devices like Mobile Phones, Cameras to PC. usually the file paths that are in the device are displayed like

```
This PC\XPERIA S\Internal Storage
```

How can i access files in this directory using C#?

```
    String dirName= @"This PC\XPERIA S\Internal Storage";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName);
```

this is what i want to do. above code is not working. I added this for you to get an idea.

Comment: `is not working` - what does it do? give you an empty array, or throw an exception?

Comment: @Chips_100 Sorry for the late reply. Gives me an `DirectoryNotFoundException`. This is fine because the above path is recognized as a relative path in debug directory. i need absolute paths to the files in the above directory so i can access 'em.